# Scrapy high CPU usage

Tags: scrapy

I have a very simple test spider which does no parsing. However I'm passing a large number of urls (500k) to the spider in the start_requests method and seeing very high (99/100%) cpu usage. Is this the expected behaviour? if so how can I optimize this (perhaps batching and using spider_idle?)

```
class TestSpider(Spider):

    name = 'test_spider'
    allowed_domains = 'mydomain.com'

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Spider, self).__init__(**kw)
        urls_list = kw.get('urls')
        if urls_list:
            self.urls_list = urls_list

    def parse(self, response):
        pass

    def start_requests(self):
        with open(self.urls_list, 'rb') as urls:
            for url in urls:
                yield Request(url, self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem here is that you are scraping too many links, try adding a *Rule* to avoid scraping links that didnt contains what you want.

Scrapy provides really useful Docs, check them out!:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html